# Custom devise views ignored in production enviroment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, railsapps

I'm using custom devise views created by the rails-prelaunch template - https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-prelaunch-signup

In development, everything works fine. I see the devise views I'm expecting (from the views/devise folder).

However, as soon as I switch to production, the app starts using the default devise gem views.

Any ideas as to what might be going on?

Thanks!

Comment: The gem is 'devise', not 'device'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-created the app, and things just worked. It turns out that there was a problem accessing the template.

I still don't know why the common solutions didn't work, as things seemed to be setup correctly.

Comment: I got the same problem. What do you mean by re-created the app ? Re-generating the devise view ?

Comment: @Douglas, There were problems when I was generating the app with the application template. I didn't notice these the first time around, but basically the app was not installing correctly. I tried regenerating the app, and it worked fine the second time. Here's a link to a page with more info - http://railsapps.github.io/rails-prelaunch-signup/